# Is this an example of a semantic violation of encapsulation and if so how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, encapsulation

If I have an interface for a Server like this...

```
interface IServer
{
    void Login();
    void Post();
    void Get();
}
```

...where `Post` and `Get` don't work unless you've done `Login` first. Is it a semantic violation of encapsulation, since it makes your use of the interface implicitly dependent on the implementation? How would you fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My idea:

```
interface IServer 
{
    ISession Authenticate();
}

interface ISession 
{
    IServer Server{get;}
    void Post();
    void Get();
}
```

Ignore that if you are accessibly of "mud":

[MUD]

> to clarify this: imho you have to think about software design as you
>   would create a product... do you really want a safe for all your
>   valueable things where you can push a button "open" instead of FIRST
>   input the code on it? this is just an analogy for your use-case...
>
> an implementator can just call post and get before he validates...
>
> another widely used approach are access-tokens and the use of it like
>   here:'
>
> interface IServer{      // returns the required token       string
>   Authenticate();       void Post(string token);        void Get(string token);
>     }
>
> but i think, that's wrong too...
>
> you can see and maybe call methods, which you are not allowed to
>   see/call before login... if the implementator just not checks if
>   "token" is correct, you have a security risk in here...
>
> if you divide the logic into several layers (guest/unauthenticated,
>   authenticated/session, and (for example) adminsession) you get clean
>   separation of logic and a lot more semantic usefullness....
>
> *I PERSONALLY* write code EVER in way, that good framework-builders would write code... it has the be reuseable, even after years, very
>   easy and clear.

[/MUD]

Comment: sorry I READ "How would you fix it?"

Comment: The question was, "How would you fix it?" I think this answers that question quite nicely

Comment: I think you were better off with your original answer ;)

Comment: as i can see, you think a lot of things, but don't provide a better answer ;) c'mon, tell us what's the right solution and description

Comment: I'm on your side here. Your original answer is brilliant (as evidenced by the votes). What you added just muddies the answer.

Comment: Is your intention to use property injection with ISession to set it's Server property? If not, I don't see what the point of it is- there is no reason for the concrete implementation to do anything with it unless you say so in the documentation. I was thinking do the same thing except make the "Execute" function take an IServer so that it is explicit, but your way makes sense too.

Comment: not injectable here...

implementation can get the IServer in the construction with Authenticate...
how this will be done it completely free -- for the use with DI, you can modify that pattern, too -- it's not the point.

i only want to show, that you should split the access-layers into different interfaces which construct each-other programatically in implementation.

Answer (score 6):

An interface in C# is just a formal contract ensuring certain properties (presence of methods). It does not capture the full semantic contract that the developer had in mind. In that sense **using an interface never guarantees the caller that he can just call any method he wants**.

The same goes for any method such as `File.WriteAllText(path, text)`. You can't just pass in null as the path, even though the formal interface allows it. The documented, enforced runtime contract prevents you from doing that.

Back to your code: **The caller does not depend on the implementation of the interface. He depends on the contract of it** (which is not stated in C#).

Comment: Even though using an interface doesn't guarantee the caller he can call any method he wants, for the best design wouldn't you want to MAXIMIZE how safe it is to call whatever you want? If I split the interface in two like TheHe suggests the contract is suggested in the design of the interfaces making it somewhat self documenting. I could make interfaces however I want if I just rely on the documentation to explain them- I'm just talking about best practices.

Comment: Yes, TheHe's code is clearly an improvement. The responsibilities are split clearly and the interface is kind of fail-safe to use.; I was addressing the part of your question where you ask if your code violates encapsulation: My answer is "no". This is not a problem of encapsulation. Maybe a problem of single responsibility.